# Why is Muhsin bin Ali bin Abi Talib not considered among imams of Shia?

Tags: caliph

We know Shias accept Hassan and hussain among twelve imams.

Why don't shia accept Muhsin , the third male offspring of Ali and Fatima as an imam among the twelve imams? Even though they admit that he was a male.

Answer (score 2):

### Because he died as an infant or was still-born

---

There are 2 ideas about when Muhsin died:

- He was [still born](http://www.seratonline.com/8668/hazrat-mohsin-ibn-ali-a-s-a-victim-of-oppression-and-terrorism/)
- He died as an [infant](http://www.iranicaonline.org/articles/fatema#i).

---

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhsin_ibn_Ali):

> In Shi'a belief, he was the unborn child of Fatimah miscarried after she was crushed behind a door during the events of Umar at Fatimah's house, when Umar and Abu Bakr attacked Fatima and Ali's house in order to force Ali into submission.
>
> Sunnis, however disagree and insist that Muhsin ibn Ali died in his infancy of natural causes.

And Allah knows best.

Comment: What is the criteria for imam in shia? Muhsin meets the criteria of progeny of Ali and Fatima.

Comment: Shia Imams are chosen by Allah swt.

Comment: What was hussain when Ali was alive and imam

Comment: Didn't you see what I said in my answer, Shias believe that he was stillborn so how could he be imam?